# What does the size argument of setvbuf mean for an unbuffered stream?

Tags: c, file-io, language-lawyer, c-standard-library

The function `setvbuf()` can be used to make a stream unbuffered:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size);
```

- What does the value of the `size` argument mean when the `mode` is passed as `_IONBF`?
- Will the buffer be allocated?
- Is it OK to pass `0`?

Comment: You'll have to look at the source code of your CRT.  But pretty safe to assume that the values of buffer and size are irrelevant, no allocation occurs when you pass buffer=NULL and a non-NULL buffer will never be used.  Library authors do apply the principle of least-surprise.

Comment: Clearly it *should* be ignored in this case, and clearly 0 is the appropriate value to pass.  (That is, if you passed any number other than 0, it would still be ignored, and nothing would be allocated, but the call would look horribly misleading.)  But different two man pages I've just looked at don't come out and say this explicitly.  Perhaps you might want to add the `language-lawyer` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version (C11) of the C Standard says:

> **7.21.5.6 The `setvbuf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
>                char * restrict buf,
>                int mode, size_t size);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `setvbuf` function may be used only after the stream pointed to by `stream` has been associated with an open file and before any other operation (other than an unsuccessful call to `setvbuf`) is performed on the stream. The argument `mode` determines how stream will be buffered, as follows: `_IOFBF` causes input/output to be fully buffered; `_IOLBF` causes input/output to be line buffered; `_IONBF` causes input/output to be unbuffered. If `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function<sup>273</sup>) and the argument `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` may determine the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function. The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `setvbuf` function returns zero on success, or nonzero if an invalid value is given for `mode` or if the request cannot be honored.

The use of the conditional tense gives a lot of flexibility for the library author as to how to implement `setvbuf()`.

Steve Summit arguments this way:

*Clearly `size` should be ignored if `mode` is passed as `_IONBF`, and clearly `0` is the appropriate value to pass. (That is, if you passed any number other than 0, it would still be ignored, and nothing would be allocated, but the call would look horribly misleading.) But two different man pages I've just looked at don't come out and say this explicitly.*

The C Standard does indeed allow for `size` to be ignored for all cases and it does make sense that it be ignored for the unbuffered case.

I found an alternative that makes sense too: `setvbuf()` could still specify the buffer to be used by the stream output functions, static or allocated, as long as the stream functions do not keep any unflushed output in it when they return. For example, `printf` could use this buffer to compose its output and flush it by chunks. The C Standard does **not** specify that unbuffered streams use a system call for each byte written to the output stream's system handle. These are implementation details beyond the scope of the Standard.

If `setvbuf()` indeed tries to allocate `size` bytes and fails, it may return a non zero value and not make the stream unbuffered. An unexpected behavior that would still be conformant. Try `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, SIZE_MAX);`

Comment: It is not that straight-forward.  Even if you ask for no buffering then buffering might still occur for text files.  Stuff like character set translation and handling line ending might require a (small) buffer. All highly OS-specific.  The CRT will typically switch to a small internal buffer.  Have a look-see.